# What is the most efficient way to parse a text file by lines, where some values have enclosed carriage return characters (\r), in .net?

Tags: c#, .net, f#

I need to transfer some data from one database to another database.
Unfortunately, the only means of getting hold of the data from the source database is via flat file extracts.
The source database contains tables with xml columns.
The xml values have many \r characters. All values (including xml values) are enclosed in quotes. The line separators are the Windows standard \r\n.

I want to write a console app to read the flat files and load them into the target database. The problem is that the standard [StreamReader.Readline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.streamreader.readline?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_StreamReader_ReadLine) does not differentiate between \r, \n and \r\n. So every time I call ReadLine it will give me a line that ends in the wrong place.

I suppose the simplest solution would be to ReadToEnd and then split by \r\n, but this would have a large memory footprint.

Another solution would be to implement my own ReadLine function based on Read, but I am sure that is not going to be as fast as the natively implemented ReadLine.

What other options are there?

Comment: Use a CSV reader nuget package.

Comment: [TextFieldParser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.fileio.textfieldparser?view=netframework-4.7.2) but you need to check about the embedded newline problem

Comment: `I suppose the simplest solution would be to ReadToEnd` wrong, you will spend a long time getting this right. as for speed, the fastest way will be to get it all up into memory and use someone-elses proven fast library. However who knows you might be able to come up with something even faster if you wanted to spend the time and keep fixing the edge cases

Comment: @TheGeneral unless I am mistaken, ReadToEnd returns a string (in memory) which has a method to split based on some other string. So the whole operation is a single line.

Comment: Not knowing the nature of your data, if it has many degrees of freedom, you will have a lot of trouble trying to use split, or any other trivial method to parse it. Just use a CSV parser. If it is very very very trivial data, then it might just be worth looking at parsing your self, however the very fact you are asking this question seems to point the otherway.

Comment: `MemoryMappedFile` can sometimes be really fast

Comment: You mentioned problems with newline chars but what are other characteristics. Size of files? Xml represents the table schema? Does speed really matter or is ease simple the goal?

Comment: File size is up to 2gb. The xml is the data that is contained in one of the columns. So each row has a different xml value. It is not a schema it is just structured data in a column. As for speed vs ease, I guess I need to find a balance; I don’t want to spend 30 minutes processing one file.